# Converting a string into a single array with multiple entries

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, ecmascript-6

I have a variable with a string attached to it. I'm trying to convert this string into an array with each new line being a new entry.

```
const song = `Baby Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Baby Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Baby Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Baby Shark!`
```

I expecting something like this: ["Baby Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo", "Baby Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo", "Baby Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo", "Baby Shark!"]

I'm drawing a blank what would be the cleanest way to solve this?

Comment: Use the split() function on string, splitting on newline characters '\n'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split on a newline `\n`:

```js
const song = `Baby Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Baby Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Baby Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Baby Shark!`;
const arr = song.split("\n");
console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```